# Analytics Report chart is not getting loaded in some Profiles

Tags: visualforce, reports-folder

I am struggling with an issue in a VF page. i have analytics report chart which is displaying some data in VF page. on clicking the chart, the page is redirectd to the particular report and data is displayed. This chart works fine in System admin profile.

[image]

but in other profile the below error is being shown. unable to find the error can any one help me on this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the folder that contains that report and make sure that the profile have access to those reports. Do the same on the Dashboard folder.

To do this go to:

1. **Reports**-> select the folder that contains the reports.
2. On the **right end click the icon that appears**, select **"share"**
3. On the next window make sure that those profiles that your are mentioning have access to the folder. Same process for Dashboards.

Comment: The Report is in unfiled Public Reports